# Dúvida na Normalização de Dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Tenho uma dúvida referente à normalização.
Tenho 3 tabelas: Veículos, Filtros e Combinações. Funciona assim, na tabela Combinações eu seleciono a ID do Veículo na tabela Veículo e 4 filtros relacionados a cada carro na tabela Filtros . Ex.:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A estrutura é aceitável pelas regras da normalização? ou teria que criar 4 tabelas de FiltrosN?
Isso está vinculado em como eu vou chamar no PHP. Por exemplo:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Combinações c
             JOIN Veiculos v
             ON c.id = a.veiculo
                 JOIN Filtros f
                 ON..."       <<--- É aqui que estou em dúvida
```

Como eu vinculo a tabela Filtros a tabela Combinações ? e como eu chamaria um `echo' Filtro de Oleo, Filtro Ar, Filtro Cabine, Filtro Combustivel relacionando com a tabela Filtros?

Comment: Depende de que forma normal está falando, em alguma está sim, em outra não está, eu acho porque normalização não é uma regra mágica que resolve problemas, você tem um problema e tudo precisa ser normalizado para atender a demanda dele, sem saber a exata demanda não tem como saber se está certo ou não. Infelizmente toda vez que escrevo isso a pessoa repete o que ela já disse e não detalha a demanda e aí ficar difícil dizer se está certo. Não sei para que serve essas peças nas avarias, então não sei se está normalizado certo. A segunda parte deve ter dup,já vi várias vezes respostas de 3 tabelas

Comment: A demanda que você diz é em termos de tráfego? quantidade de consultas por tempo? Não entendi...

Comment: Não sei se serei repetitivo, mas vou tentar explicar como funciona meu sistema: é um sistema para oficina mecânica, então tenho uma lista de veículos e uma lista de peças especifica de cada veículo (por exemplo: Spin - Pneu X - Roda X - Calota X - Parafuso X ; Palio - Pneu Y - Roda Y - Calota Y - Parafuso Y...).
Assim ao consultar um veículo eu vou saber qual roda, calota, parafuso, pneu eu uso...
(Obs.: a imagem da tabela foi um exemplo que eu achei pronto, não sei se está atrapalhando)

Comment: Quantas peças pode ter nisso? Sempre 4, não pode ter 3 e não pode ter 5?

Comment: Sim, sempre 4 peças.

Comment: Então a resposta que você aceitou está errada.

Comment: É...acabei de perceber. Fiz mas deu um 'falso-positivo'...

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei como realmente funciona. Agora acho que está mais compreensível rsrs...observe que na tabela Filtros tem todos os filtros, não importando sua aplicação (ar, óleo, ...) isso eu filtro no php

Comment: O problema é que agora tem duas respostas erradas na sua pergunta porque ela não foi feita de forma adequada desde o início, e pior, tem positivos nas duas.

Comment: Posso ter errado na formulação da pergunta inicial, mas não vejo como respostas erradas, tanto que a estrutura inicial que eu fiz estava conforme essa última resposta. Mas eu mudei pq aumentava muito a quantidade de informações armazenadas...

Comment: Você acabou de dizer que elas estão erradas mesmo afirmando que não estão.

Comment: Bom...podemos ficar debatendo filosoficamente o sigificado das frases...porém não disse que estavam erradas, disse que não é a melhor opção, existem boas e más opções, o que não as classificam como erradas...segue o jogo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para atender ao que você precisa, de forma correta, você deve alterar a tabela de avarias para uma estrutura de crescimento "vertical":

[image: Relacionamento 1->N]

Porque, se cada registro da tabela de peças virar uma coluna na tabela de avarias, sempre que criar um registro novo você terá executar "alter table" na tabela de avarias.

Daí sua consulta ficaria:

```
select * from Avarias a
 join Veiculos v on v.idveiculo=a.idveiculo
 join Pecas p on p.idpeca=a.idpeca
```

Comment: Eu mudei a estrutura! Eu já tentei assim também, mas não deu certo...

Comment: O problema de fazer assim é que teria muitas linhas para cada veiculo. Porém se não houver outra forma...

Comment: @Nosredna, na minha resposta, a tabela "suja" é só o N-N avarias_pecas; e as outras 3 ficariam mais práticas para controle. São formas diferentes de fazer

Comment: @LeonardoNegrão entendi... Eu tinha feito outra forma também, tipo: tabela Combinações,  tabela Veiculo, tabela Filtro Ar, tabela Filtro Oleo, tabela Filtro Cabine, tabela Filtro Combustivel - ai eu relacionava cada tabelas 'Filtros' e a tabela 'Veiculo' na tabela 'Combinações'

Comment: @Nosredna você perguntou qual forma correta de se fazer. A forma correta é assim. Agora, se por outro lado você quer "mostrar de alguma outra forma", utilize a linguagem de programação (php,perl,.net,java) para montar um html ou no formulário conforme você quiser. Mas o banco de dados normalizado pra esse caso é assim.

Answer (score 1):

acredito que o melhor seria assim:

**tabela veículos:** continua idêntica

**tabela Peças:** continua idêntica

**tabela Avarias:** Você precisa construir um relacionamento e as primeiras perguntas são:

1) Um veículo pode ter mais de uma avaria e a avaria mais de um veículo? Acredito que não.

2) Uma avaria pode precisar ter mais de uma peça e a mesma peça estar em várias avarias? Acredito que sim e isso é uma relação **N - N**

Então você precisa criar uma tabela intermediária para o relacionamento **N para N** (pois ambos podem conter mais de uma linha de outra tabela, como em um carrinho de compras).

Então você terá 4 tabelas:

1. Veiculos
2. Avarias
3. Peças
4. avarias_pecas (id, veiculo_id, avaria_id, peca_id) <-- a nova que fará a ponte do relacionamento.

Assim você poderá fazer o Join de várias formas, por exemplo:

```
// todas as peças que precisou em uma avaria
select pecas, from avarias_pecas ap, pecas p where ap.peca_id = p.id and avaria_id=X;

//todas as avarias de um veiculo
select veiculo from veiculos v, avarias a where v.id = a.veiculo_id where v.id=X;
```

Ok? Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Entendi seu comentário, eu trabalho com Magento e já fiz alguns bancos de lojas virtuais, em todos fiz uma tabela para "peças" e outra para categorias (como você citou os tipos de filtros) uma terceira tabela para filtros_categorias e outra filtros_veiculos; assim você controla e extrai dados como "filtros para determinados tipos de veículos", "todos os veículos que utilizam aquele filtro" e até exibi-lo em mais de uma situação caso seja um produto mais genérico. Boa sorte com seu banco!